# How to reduce space using \cventry in Awesome CV

Tags: awesome-cv

I am working on Awesome CV (downloaded from here https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-cv/dfnvtnhzhhbm). I would like to delete the space between "Languages" and the itemised list and have it look like this : [image]

Here is the code I am using :

```
\documentclass[]{awesome-cv}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newenvironment{cvitems*}[1][2]
 {\setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}%
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}%
  \begin{multicols}{#1}
  \begin{cvitems}}
 {\end{cvitems}%
  \end{multicols}
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{2mm}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Personal Data
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Essentials
\name{Some}{Name}
\address{An Address, 3245}
\mobile{(+57) 45-45654-434} 
%%% Social
\email{somethingHere@gmail.com}
\homepage{www.SomePage.com}
\github{Someone2}
\linkedin{Someone2}
%%% Optionals
\position{My Position}
\quote{``I am me.''}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Content
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Make a footer for CV with three arguments(<left>, <center>, <right>)
\makecvfooter
  {\today}
  {My Resume}
  {\thepage}

\begin{document}
%%% Make a header for CV with personal data
\makecvheader

\cvsection{Skills}
\begin{cventries}
  \cventry
{} % Job title
{Languages} % Organization
{} % Location
{} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities
\begin{cvitems*}[4]
\item \textbf{Spanish}
\item \textbf{German}
\item \textbf{Italian}: 
\item \textbf{French}: 
\color{white}\item \textbf{smh}: 
\item item 6 
\end{cvitems*}
}
\end{cventries}
\color{black}
\begin{cventries}
  \cventry
{} % Job title
{Programming} % Organization
{} % Location
{} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities
\begin{cvitems*}[4]
\item \textbf{Languages}: Python \LaTeX
\color{white}
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item 
\item item 6 with words describing it
\end{cvitems*}
}
\end{cventries}
```

And here is the output :
[image]

Thank you in advance for your help;

Comment: Use `\vspace{-2\baselineskip}%` instead of `\vspace{-\baselineskip}%`  inside`\newenvironment{cvitems*`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future, using `\vspace{-2\baselineskip}%` doesn't completely solve the problem. Here's the output:

[image]

The best I could do was this code :

```
\documentclass[]{awesome-cv}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newenvironment{cvitems*}[1][2]
 {\setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}%
  \vspace{-2\baselineskip}%
  \begin{multicols}{#1}
  \begin{cvitems}}
 {\end{cvitems}%
  \end{multicols}
  \vspace{+0\baselineskip}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Personal Data
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Essentials
\name{Some}{Name}
\address{An Address, 3245}
\mobile{(+57) 45-45654-434} 
%%% Social
\email{somethingHere@gmail.com}
\homepage{www.SomePage.com}
\github{Someone2}
\linkedin{Someone2}
%%% Optionals
\position{My Position}
\quote{``I am me.''}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Content
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Make a footer for CV with three arguments(<left>, <center>, <right>)
\makecvfooter
  {\today}
  {My Resume}
  {\thepage}

\begin{document}
%%% Make a header for CV with personal data
\makecvheader

\cvsection{Skills}
\begin{cventries}
  \cventry
{} % Job title
{Languages} % Organization
{} % Location
{} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities
\begin{cvitems*}[2]
\item \textbf{Spanish}
\item \textbf{German}
\item \textbf{Italian}
\item \textbf{French}
\end{cvitems*}
}
\end{cventries}
\color{black}
\begin{cventries}
  \cventry
{} % Job title
{Programming} % Organization
{} % Location
{} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) of tasks/responsibilities
\begin{cvitems*}[4]
\item \textbf{Languages}: Python \LaTeX
\end{cvitems*}
}
\end{cventries}
```

And here's the output :

[image]

Hope it helps.